# My API is returning undefined instead of response value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks

I'm consuming an API using Axios in React, but when i come to set the response in a State so I may use the data, it is undefined. The funny thing is, if I put console.log inside `Get.js` I see the array perfectly. Am I returning the value the wrong way ?

PS: When I use console.log inside the `Get.js`,inside the 2nd `.then`, it prints two times the array. Why ?

**MainPage.jsx**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { axiosGet } from '../../services/Get';
import { Header } from '../../components/Header/';
import { Welcome } from '../../components/Welcome/';

export const MainPage = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(axiosGet());
    setData(axiosGet());
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Welcome />
      {data.length &&
        data.map(obj => {
        <p key={obj.id}>obj.name</p>;
    })}
    </>
  );
```

**Get.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export function axiosGet() {
  axios
    .get(
      `https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=a6a08e14b07f41d09e846ec3c01e5db0&dates=2019-10-10,2022-03-01&page=2`
    )
    .then(res => {
      return res.data.results;
    })
    .then(arr => {
      return arr;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('oops! error: ' + err);
    });
}
```

if I change the `Get.js` code at this piece of code:

```
.then(res => {
          return res.data.results;
        })
        .then(arr => {
          console.log(arr)
          return arr;
        })
```

I got this:

```
Array(20) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
​
0: Object { slug: "forza-horizon-5", name: "Forza Horizon 5", playtime: 11, … }
​
1: Object { slug: "call-of-duty-modern-warfare", name: "Call of Duty: Modern Warfare (2019)", playtime: 0, … }
​
2: Object { slug: "resident-evil-village", name: "Resident Evil: Village", playtime: 16, … }
​
3: Object { slug: "assassins-creed-valhalla", name: "Assassin's Creed Valhalla", playtime: 0, … }
​
4: Object { slug: "genshin-impact", name: "Genshin Impact", playtime: 0, … }
​
5: Object { slug: "mafia", name: "Mafia: Definitive Edition", playtime: 9, … }
​
6: Object { slug: "superhot-mind-control-delete", name: "SUPERHOT: MIND CONTROL DELETE", playtime: 2, … }
​
7: Object { slug: "valheim", name: "Valheim", playtime: 11, … }
​
8: Object { slug: "it-takes-two-2", name: "It Takes Two", playtime: 11, … }
​
9: Object { slug: "deep-rock-galactic", name: "Deep Rock Galactic", playtime: 6, … }
​
10: Object { slug: "risk-of-rain-2", name: "Risk of Rain 2", playtime: 7, … }
​
11: Object { slug: "tell-me-why", name: "Tell Me Why", playtime: 2, … }
​
12: Object { slug: "factorio", name: "Factorio", playtime: 17, … }
​
13: Object { slug: "ghostrunner", name: "Ghostrunner", playtime: 4, … }
​
14: Object { slug: "marvels-avengers", name: "Marvel’s Avengers", playtime: 14, … }
​
15: Object { slug: "mafia-iii-definitive-edition", name: "Mafia III: Definitive Edition", playtime: 0, … }
​
16: Object { slug: "guardians-of-the-galaxy", name: "Marvel's Guardians of the Galaxy", playtime: 8, … }
​
17: Object { slug: "need-for-speed-heat", name: "Need for Speed Heat", playtime: 3, … }
​
18: Object { slug: "marvels-spider-man-miles-morales", name: "Marvel's Spider-Man: Miles Morales", playtime: 0, … }
​
19: Object { slug: "streets-of-rage-4", name: "Streets of Rage 4", playtime: 4, … }
​
length: 20
​
<prototype>: Array []
Get.js:12:15
```

Comment: does not your `useEffect` keeps running that seems to be the issue to me, wrap it with empty array ...cause you need to load data one time 
`useEffect(()=> your get call, [])`

Comment: Also, you are doing data.map while data may not even be there so better to check `data.length && data.map`

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: data is undefined`, I did the two changes you suggest.

Comment: your useEffect useEffect(() => {
    console.log(axiosGet());
    setData(axiosGet());
  });
your map function  {data.length && data.map(obj => <p key={obj.someProp}>obj.name</p>;)}
your map is incorrect :)

Comment: can you provide console.log of your get call please ? 
probably it is nested inside another prop or something hence giving you undefined

Comment: you don't need obj = <p>... just `{data.map(obj => <p key={something}>{obj.name}</p>)}`

Comment: I edited my question Anuj, take a look

Comment: please change your map too

Comment: it's done Anuj.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244408/discussion-between-anuj-and-maiky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `axiosGet` doesn't actually return anything.

You can't though get it to directly return the API data, since that is only retrieved asynchronously. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) for lots of discussion as to how to get the response from asynchronous requests and use it in your code.

In your case probably the easiest solution is to have `axiosGet` return the promise that `axios.get` (and your subsequent `.then` calls from it) gives you, and then `await` that in your `useEffect` so that you can set the state in your component to it.

So I would make the following changes:

First  add the `return` statement to `axiosGet`:

```
export function axiosGet() {
  return axios
    .get(
      `https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=a6a08e14b07f41d09e846ec3c01e5db0&dates=2019-10-10,2022-03-01&page=2`
    )
    .then(res => {
      return res.data.results;
    })
    .then(arr => {
      return arr;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('oops! error: ' + err);
    });
}
```

and adjust the `useEffect` in your component as follows:

```
useEffect(async () => {
  const apiData = await axiosGet();
  setData(apiData);
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you Robin. I got my problem fixed and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 2):

The function `axios.get()` returns a Promise of the data you want.
You need to modify your code to return this promise to the calling function:

```js
export function axiosGet() {
  return axios
   .get(
      `https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=a6a08e14b07f41d09e846ec3c01e5db0&dates=2019-10-10,2022-03-01&page=2`
    )
```

And then you need to `await` for an answer (to go from a Promise to the data):

```js
useEffect(async () => {
  console.log(await axiosGet());
  setData(await axiosGet());
}, []);
```